# Boost 1.55 Python with Windows Visual Studio 2013, Link Error

Tags: python-2.7, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, boost-python

I download boost1.55 zip from official website and then build with command `bootstrap` and `b2`.
And I tried example code, but it has a link error.

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'
```

Below is what I did.

1. New project win32 Console application, DLL empty.
2. Add include path, library path in `VC++ DIRECTORIES` like the below.

   ```
   INCLUDE DIRECTORIES: C:\boost\boost_1_55_0;C:\Python27\include 
   LIBRARY DIRECTORIES: C:\boost\boost_1_55_0\libs;C:\Python27\libs
   ```

.

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set);
}
```

**Edit**

If i add the library directory, `C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib`like an answer below, it make many errors happen, around 200
below is just the part of errors.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: hello, Configuration: Debug Win32
>   ------ 1>  hello.cpp 1>c:\python27\include\pymath.h(22): warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage 1>          c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\math.h(516) : see
>   previous definition of 'round' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(190): warning C4273: '_hypot'
>   : inconsistent dll linkage 1>          c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\math.h(538) : see
>   previous definition of '_hypot' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(206): warning C4273: 'round' :
>   inconsistent dll linkage 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 12.0\vc\include\math.h(516) : see previous definition of
>   'round' 1>c:\boost_1_55_0\boost\python\opaque_pointer_converter.hpp :
>   warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be
>   represented in the current code page (949). Save the file in Unicode
>   format to prevent data loss
>   1>c:\boost_1_55_0\boost\python\return_opaque_pointer.hpp : warning
>   C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the
>   current code page (949). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent
>   data loss 1>     Creating library C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\hello\Debug\hello.lib and object
>   C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\hello\Debug\hello.exp 1>hello.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize
>   referenced in function "public: struct _object * __thiscall
>   boost::python::to_python_value,class std::allocator > const
>   &>::operator()(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)const "
>   (??R?$to_python_value@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@python@boost@@QBEPAU_object@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(builtin_converters.obj) : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(str.obj) : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(function_doc_signature.obj) :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize 1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(list.obj) : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(tuple.obj) : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(function_doc_signature.obj) :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(object_protocol.obj) : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(pickle_support.obj) : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(dict.obj) : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(str.obj) : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(from_python.obj) : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(function.obj) : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct
>   1>libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(module.obj) : error LNK2001:

Comment: Does libboost_python-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib exist in C:\boost\boost_1_55_0\libs?

Comment: It exists in `C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib` And `C:\boost_1_55_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-12.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "LIBRARY DIRECTORY" should reference `C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib` instead of `C:\boost\boost_1_55_0\libs`.